# Intel MOE java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17050 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes

Tags: java, ios, out-of-memory

I'm working with Intel's Multi-OS Engine (MOE) to run my java program on an iOS device (I am not working with Android) I am getting an out of memory error more specifically,

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17050 byte allocation
>   with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation
>   (required continguous free 32768 bytes where largest contiguous free
>   16384 bytes)

I don't understand why it's having a tough time allocating space for something so small. I analyzed the memory consumption prior to the error occurring several times and it has more than enough space as you can see in the error message. Does anyone know if Intel MOE has some type of manifest that is analogous to Android where I can set a larger heap space? Any suggestions as to how I might overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/t/solved-huge-ram-usages-prevents-app-release/1079/15) post I set my max heap size to 24mb (in main.cpp) to conserve memory space as I was running into memory issues immediately after startup. I came to the realization that limiting the heap space to a cap that is too small conversely causes memory issues as well, as noted above. I found that 124mb is suitable for my app.